# why i can't get the xprv descriptor from the bitcoin-cli listdescriptors true

Tags: wallet, output-script-descriptors, private-key-export

If I use the `listdescriptors true` command, I only receive values like (pkh, sh, tr, wpkh). Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptors contain more information than just keys. They contain information about the scripts to create. But it's all just plain text, so you should be able to see that there are xprvs contained within the descriptor string.

If you do not see them, you should still see xpubs. In that case, your wallet is a watch only wallet and doesn't have any private keys.

If you don't know what an xprv looks like, then I suggest you reevaluate what it is that you are actually trying to do. Handling private keys by hand can be dangerous and risks any funds associated with them.